# Using USB On The Go files with the stock android music app?

Tags: music-player, usb-on-the-go

I have a Huawei Accend Mate 2.  I have a flash drive with a micro USB connector (as well as a USB connecter).  I have music files on it.  Is there a way I can get the stock music app to "see" these files?  I would like to include them in playlists etc. without loading them all to the phone itself (micro SD card).

---

The only name is Music and it is version 4.7.16. The only way I can see the files is with ES File Explorer. If I tap a music file when I am in ES File Explorer, it will play but only after a little pop-up message saying something like connecting to 127.1.1.1 or something like that. It does not seem like the apps on my phone see the files on the USB drive.

---

I could but I have a bunch of playlists set up in the stock music player. I would also run into the same problem with other files like pictures and video. I expected the On The Go function would have made this a bit more seamless.

---

The phone does see the flash drive is there since it does power it.  However, I can only access the files with ES File Explorer.  Accessing them from that APP will let them play but I can not access the files without going to ES File Explorer to find them.

Comment: After connecting the USB to your mobile via OTG cable, can you see your music files stored in the USB device in your Stock Music App? Can you able to access the contents of the USB device at all using a File Manager?

Comment: Moreover: what is the "stock music app"? That very much depends on what the manufacturer put on there (or what ROM you use; e.g. CyanogenMod ships with *Apollo*, while "googlified" ROMs often use *Google Play Music*). Does your "stock music app" have a name? ;)

Comment: See [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) or contact [SE] ([here](http://android.stackexchange.com/contact))for account merging.

Comment: I verified the account info and approved the edit in this case, but yes you need to register your account and have the others merged.

Answer (score 1):

If the stock music app is confined to internal storage [sdcard]
and can access any directory in /sdcard that contains media
you can try a bind mount between the [media containing directory]
in your otg-device and a specified new directory in /sdcard

```
mkdir /sdcard/more-tunes
su
chmod 755 /sdcard/more-tunes
mount -o bind /path-to-otg-device/tunes /sdcard/more-tunes
```

just remember to unmount the /sdcard/more-tunes directory if you don't need it anymore BEFORE you delete it.

Less stressful option would be a softlink in the same[ish] way.

```
su
busybox ln -sf /path-to-otg-device/tunes /sdcard/more-tunes
```

for this approach you can just delete the symlink without risking loss of media files, but i don't know if your default app will follow the symlink.